# Return generic list from DAL

Tags: c#, list, generics

I want to create a common method which accepts query and class name as a parameter and return a generic list from DAL(Data Access Layer) Class.

```
List<Employee> empList = objDAL.GetList(Employee,"Select * FROM Employee");
List<Student> studList = objDAL.GetList(Student,"Select * FROM Student");
```

Is it possible to call from DAL Class? How can I do this?

Comment: Why are questions being down-voted without a single comment asking for corrections to be made, is this a trend now?

Comment: Even i don't know about it. If someone telling me what's the mistake then I will improve it next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider utilizing the [Repository Pattern](http://web.archive.org/web/20150404154203/https://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/):

```
public class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private DbContext db;
    private DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public Repository(DbContext ctx)
    {
        db = ctx;
        dbSet = db.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    internal IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return dbSet;
    }

    ... // Other CRUD operations
}
```

You might then instantiate repositories for these Entities:

```
private var _employees = new Repository<Employee>(dbContext);
private var _students = new Repository<Student>(dbContext);
```

And retrieve data like so:

```
return _employees.GetAll();          // IQueryable<Employee>
return _students.GetAll().ToList();  // IEnumerable<Student>
```

The repositories would become your DAL and give you generic CRUD methods, `Insert(), GetAll(), GetID(), Update(), Delete(), etc.` to interface with for each of your entities.